# Where to plug in the PowerSwitch on an ASRock K7S41GX motherboard

Tags: motherboard, power, switch

I have an ASRock K7S41GX motherboard.

I don't know where to plug in the power switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at page 20 on your manual - http://download.asrock.com/manual/K7S41GX%20Pro.pdf

You should see this: [image]

Connect your power switch to "PWRBNT" and the "GND" pin next to that and it should work.

This connector is at the bottom right of your motherboard.

Comment: many thanks - look forward to try it out!! I come back and report all my findings Greetings

Comment: additional question: well i have a plug where two cables are in  - a red one and a white one. How should i set this onto the corresponding connector? I do not know - Shcould i assume that white means ground and red is + 5 volt. I have no voltmeter here. I cannot make tests. can anybody advice here=? look forward to hear from you !! Grretings

Comment: If this is just a power switch it doesn't really matter most of the time, as it will work either way. It would only matter if it's something like a LED light, try one way then the other. Although I would guess red is the power, and white is the ground.

Comment: many thx. I will do so!!